# Powershell Script to convert txt to xlsx

Tags: excel, powershell, text-files

I want to convert a textfile to Excel Format. I use the following script from Technet:

```
# Script name: ConvertTilde.ps1 
# Created on: 2007-01-06 
# Author: Kent Finkle 
# Purpose: How Can I Convert a Tilde-Delimited File to Microsoft Excel Format? 

$s = gc C:\Scripts\Test.txt 
$s = $s -replace("~","`t") 
$s | sc C:\Scripts\Test.txt 
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application 
$xl.Visible = $true 
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Scripts\Test.txt")
$wb.SaveAs(“D:\Excel\Test.xlsx”)
```

The Script works, excel opens and imports the txt, but the saved Files are just txt files renamed to xlsx - how can I get Excel to change the File Format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would investigate the FileFormat parameter of the [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx) method, although it won't magically convert a text file into a nicely formatted workbook.

Comment: That was easy, thank you for your help:
`$xlFixedFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook
$wb.SaveAs(“D:\Excel\Test.xlsx”, $xlFixedFormat)`