# What is the cause of Error: unexpected '$' in "$" and how to convert txt file into xlsx file in R?

Tags: excel, powershell

I wanted to write a code to convert automatically a huge number of .txt files into .xlsx files (Excel). I saw a code at this page [Powershell Script to convert txt to xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560483/powershell-script-to-convert-txt-to-xlsx)
and I modified just the name and the link of the folder. But when trying to run the code I get this error message:

> Error: unexpected '$' in "$"

This is the code:

```
$xlFixedFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook 
$wb.SaveAs("C:\Users\wascal\Desktop\transfo\Test.xlsx”, $xlFixedFormat)
```

Could someone explain me the cause of the error help me to solve the issue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48ae02e7-9671-4498-bd27-44f6910c503a/excel-convert-xls-to-xlsx?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Why is R in the title then if using Powershell? R can certainly do this by itself with its many Excel modules and COM package even can run command lines.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am a new learner of R. I thought it was a R code. Please which R code can help in doing so? I mean convert a  txt files into xlsx files?

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `[` in :

```
$xlFixedFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

correct code should be

```
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your

$wb.SaveAs("C:\Users\wascal\Desktop\transfo\Test.xlsx”, $xlFixedFormat)

Has another double quote at the end of the string.